# What is the idiomatic way to query by a non-primary key attribute?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` model with a primary key on `user_id` and a unique `username`. If I knew the `user_id`, I use `session.query(User).get(user_id)`. What is the equivalent query when the attribute is not a primary key, like `session.query(User).get(username=username)`?

`session.query(User).filter_by(username=username).first()` would also return `None` if no rows are found, but it does not make it explicit that there can never be more than one rows for that query.

I wrote the following, but is this something that anyone routinely implements as a helper in their code?

```
try:
  user = session.query(User).filter_by(username=username).one()
except (NoResultFound, MultipleResultsFound):
  user = None
```

Comment: I think you need to explain why you need to make it explicit that there can't be more than one row. Explicit to whom?

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily complicated. The uniqueness constraint on the `username` field guarantees that the query will return at most one result, so there is no way that the `MultipleResultsFound` error can occur. The call to `.one()` raises an error when there is no result, but that would better be detected with `if not user` or (if you want to be more explicit) `if user == []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "idiomatic" way to query for one thing is to use `filter` and `first` or `one`, `get` is basically just a shortcut for the primary key.  If all you're asking is "is this try/accept block ok to use" then yes, it will work fine, no one would find that hard to understand.

What *would be* a bit confusing is returning `None` if there are multiple results, but if that's what you need then that works.  Given that the `username` column already has a unique constraint, this method is pretty much useless anyway, as there will never be multiple results for a username.

---

A more **reusable** solution is to use a custom [`Query`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query) subclass and add a `one_or_none` method that behaves similarly to [`one`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/16a87fe6d954def3143820217adf398d8eda42c9/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py?at=rel_1_0#cl-2450).  When creating the session, make it use this class by passing [`query_cls`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.query_cls).

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query

class MyQuery(Query):
    def one_or_none(self):
        """Return one result, or None if there are zero or >1 results."""
        ret = self.limit(2).all()

        if len(ret) == 1:
            return ret[0]
        else:
            return None

session = Session(query_cls=MyQuery)
session.query(User).filter(username="example").one_or_none()
```

Again, returning None when there are multiple results is not a typical behavior, and it's not really doing anything when there's a unique constraint anyway.

---

You could also add a specific method for querying by username, if that's a common operation. Modified from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/0dc7ab0ee5270fc69cfa) from [user Adam Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3058609/adam-smith):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import MultipleResultsFound

class MyQuery(Query):
    def get_by_username(self, username):
        ret = self.filter(username=username).limit(2).all()

        if len(ret) == 1:
            return ret[0]
        else:
            return None

session = Session(query_cls=MyQuery)
session.query(User).get_by_username("example")
```